# p:dataTable: How to sort only the data on the current page like Struts <display:table sort="page">?

Tags: sorting, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am given the task to port an old Struts 1.3 application on Jetty 9.3 to JSF/Primefaces.
The well-know Struts `<display:table>`-component has a `sort`-attribute which can have either `"list"` or `"page"` as values, meaning either to sort the entire underlying data or just the visible part of it on the current page, respectively.

How can this be emulated with JSF `<h:dataTable>` or preferably Primefaces `<p:dataTable>`?
I have consulted the Primefaces 5.3 user guide, the showcase and many internet resources and of course stackoverflow search. 
The lazy loading features of Primefaces could be a key I figured but no complete example was to be found.
Is there a complete example with say in-memory dummy data?,

Comment: there had sortBy attribute in p:column of p:dataTable. it would help?

Comment: Ye Win, nope, that will always sort the entire underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces supports lazyloading for the datatable. The feature that you can do lazy loading (no need to fully load all data upfront),  is actually provided by  actually giving you full control of any aspect of sorting, paging and filtering.

Normally you would filter, sort and then page, but that could be done in any order.

So it is very simple to just sort after you e.g. loaded the data for the right page with the right filter instead of doing the sorting before the paging.

That way you achieve the behaviour you want.